# How to solve cannot read property "length"? [reactjs]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the length of an object but am getting this error message:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

I am trying to get the length and getting a popup when the length is zero.

I tried using `this.props.storyboardTargets.length === 0`

case 1: data not available so `(!this.props.storyboardTargets)`--> `undefined`

case 2: data was there and later deletd or cleared so need to check the length

Here is my code below:

```
handleShowPopupTarget = () => {
    if (this.props.storyboardTargets && !this.props.storyboardTargets.length) {
        console.log(this.props.storyboardTargets);
        toastWarning(WARNING_MSG_NO_TARGET);
    }
};
```

Comment: And the chat that no one will ever look at because it requires clicking and knowing it is there....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it written now does not handle the issue that `this.props.storyboardTargets` may be undefined. You need to update it like so:

```
handleShowPopupTarget = () => {
    if (!this.props.storyboardTargets || !this.props.storyboardTargets.length) {
        console.log(this.props.storyboardTargets);
        toastWarning(WARNING_MSG_NO_TARGET);
    }
};
```

This means if `storyboardTargets` is undefined, **or** its length is 0, `toastWarning` will fire.

As an alternative, you could define a default prop for your component of an empty array for `storyboardTargets`. That way it would never be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that `storyboardTargets` in undefined. Try seeing if `storyboardTargets` is being passed in to the component that contains your `handleShowPopupTarget` method.

Comment: when i create board it will be !this.props.storyboardTarget and also i need to check the length of that

Answer (score -1):

use *lodash*'s **get**, it simplifies a lot those kind of buggy checks:

```
_.get(this.props, 'storyboardTargets.length', 'default'); // you could use 0 instead of 'default' in your case
```

Answer (score -1):

Your  original code was

```
if (!this.props.storyboardTargets.length) {
```

And it fails because `this.props.storyboardTargets` is undefined and well you can not read properties of something that is undefined so it throws an error.

So after that you listened to advice and changed your code to be

```
if (this.props.storyboardTargets && !this.props.storyboardTargets.length)
```

So now this stops the undefined error from happening on this line because the truthy check on `this.props.storyboardTargets` prevents the evaluation of the second half of the code. So that means the code will not go into the `if`. but you WANT it to go into the if statement if it is not defined.

So what you need to do is change it to be an OR check so if it is NOT defined OR it does not have a length

```
if (!this.props.storyboardTargets || !this.props.storyboardTargets.length)
```

Now it goes into the if statement id it is undefined and will not throw the error.

The other solution is to see that it is undefined and set it to a default value

```
this.props.storyboardTargets = this.props.storyboardTargets || []
if (!this.props.storyboardTargets.length)
```

Now if the array is undefined, it sets it to an empty array and the if check will work correctly. Changing the data might not be the best solution if other things rely on undefined.

Comment: LOL, worked through the problem in the comments, write an answer that summarized my comments, and get pinged with a downvote. Thank you down voter!